# Question about perpendicular diagonals in a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to have perpendicular diagonals in a trapezoid without having a rhombus?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: draw two orthogonal congruent segments $AB$ and $CD$, meeting in $P$, such that $AP=CP$ and $BP=DP$. Then $ACBD$ is an isosceles trapezoid with orthogonal diagonals.

Comment: ...if, of course, $\;AC\neq BD\;$ , otherwise this is a parallelogram and thus a rhombus (in fact, even a square)

Comment: Yes, all right.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a pair of perpendicular lines in the plane intersecting at $O$. Then draw a pair of parallel lines which aren't parallel to the first pair and which contain 
the intersection $O$ between them. Then there are four points of intersections of these four lines lines, and together they form a trapezoid with perpendicular diagonals. (The requirement that $O$ be between the second pair of lines ensures that the perpendicular lines are diagonals rather than sides of the trapezoid.) The case of a rhombus occurs when $O$ is equidistant from the second pair of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Much variation is possible in their relative placement. Good to demonstrate all possibile variations by hand.

By any combination of rotation or translation, slide a thick transparent plastic sheet  with a *parallel pair* of lines drawn on it (that we normally use to project text/figures during presentations) over a fixed paper on which a sufficiently big *cross* is drawn. Join the intersection points.

The above can be implemented by Java  e.g., Geometer's SketchPad, where the *cross*  and *parallel pair* can be "tracked" or rigidly fixed up in relative motion to see the required trapezium vertices at points of intersections of *cross* and *parallel pair*.